# AppBarLayout not collapsing on scroll

Tags: android, android-fragments, scroll, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I'm trying to make something similar to the example seen [here](https://github.com/saulmm/CoordinatorBehaviorExample), only that the `CircleImageView` is inside toolbar already. What I want to achieve is to narrow down the toolbar and make the image smaller as I scroll down.

I tried following multiple tutorials on this case but still didn't manage to get it working.

**activity_settings.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_collapsing"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/btn_back"
                        android:layout_width="56dp"
                        android:layout_height="56dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="-16dp"
                        android:padding="16dp"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_white" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textview_title"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btn_back"
                        android:text="@string/settings"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />

                    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                        android:id="@+id/profile_image"
                        android:layout_width="96dp"
                        android:layout_height="96dp"
                        android:layout_below="@id/textview_title"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_profile_placeholder"
                        app:civ_border_color="@color/white"
                        app:civ_border_width="2dp"
                        app:civ_border_overlay="true"/>
                </RelativeLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/appbar"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The `FrameLayout` gets replaced with a separate fragment which contains `PreferenceScreen` with `PreferenceCategory, EditTextPreference and Preference` inside it. That piece of fragment itself is scrollable, I know however that FrameLayout, which is initially present in activity and replaced `onCreate`, is not. Could that be the problem? If so, is there a way to keep the fragment injection and still get it to work or does it all have to be in one layout file?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

replace this in toolbar

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/appColor"
            android:elevation="6dp"
            android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" >

                     ....

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Did that, what happens now is that the toolbar is already narrow when I open the activity (due to `android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"`). But again, nothing changes. I changed layout_height back to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` and it's all still the same.

Comment: remove   <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout @Ziga

Comment: Still nothing I'm afraid. 

Removed `CollapsingToolbarLayout`
My Toolbar now looks like this:
`<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">`